# Why does Django create an index on a unique field explicitly

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.3

**Update**: Simplifying the Q on experimenting with `psql` further:

For the following Django model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
```

`pg_dump` (PostgreSQL 9.3) shows the following table & constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY book ADD CONSTRAINT book_name_key UNIQUE (name);

CREATE INDEX book_name_like ON book USING btree (name text_pattern_ops);
```

But PostgreSQL [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-unique.html) says:

> PostgreSQL **automatically creates** a unique index when a unique
>   constraint [...] is defined for a table.
>
> [...] there's
>   **no need to manually create** indexes on unique columns; doing so would
>   just duplicate the automatically-created index.

**Question**: Why is Django creating an index on a unique column then? Maybe the justification is that it's using the operator class `text_pattern_ops`, hence Django needs to add another index. If that's the case, a better way would be to interpret `unique=True` constraint by Django as this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX book_name_like ON book USING btree (name text_pattern_ops);
```

and not have the `UNIQUE` constraint in the column at all. Thus a single `UNIQUE INDEX` with `text_pattern_ops` would result in DB not creating an implicit index for `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Is that pg_dump SQL the same as the output of [Django's `sqlall` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-app-label-app-label)?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry With Django 1.7, I'm using `sqlmigrate` which should do the same thing as `sqlall` for migrated apps. And yes, the sql is similar. It has a unique constraint in the create table statement and another create index statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Detailed discussion in bug report: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24082

Triage: Accepted to skip index when `db_index=False` (with `unique=True`)

Answer (score 26):

The heart of the issue is this guarantee made in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#unique):

> Note that when `unique` is `True` you don’t need to specify `db_index`, because `unique` implies the creation of an index.

So by Django's contract, `unique=True` implies `db_index=True`, and `db_index=True` means that Django has to create the `text_pattern_ops` index to support all lookup types (see [ticket 12234](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12234)).

As for just using a single unique index, the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-opclass.html) says that that won't cover all lookup types:

> Note that you should also create an index with the default operator class if you want queries involving ordinary <, <=, >, or >= comparisons to use an index. Such queries cannot use the xxx_pattern_ops operator classes.

You can try adding both `unique=True` and `db_index=False`.

Comment: I've tried `db_index=False` with `unique=True`. It doesn't help. I feel the premise of creating an index for unique fields by Django is incorrect (atleast for PostgreSQL & some other DB). More details in this bug report https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24082 . Regarding bug 12234, creating a unique index would be a better solution in place of unique constraint and index.

Comment: @buffer: I posted my thoughts in the bug report, but briefly: I agree that it would be better if Django didn't do this, but since that's the documented behavior you may be stuck with it for a while (and I agree that it's a bug that an explicit `db_index=False` doesn't prevent the creation of the index). As for your suggestion to create a single unique index, the PostgreSQL documentation I quoted above makes it clear that that won't work.

Comment: Agreed with first suggestion, doubt about the second. I'll carry on the discussion in the bug report.